# Pin Protect (Salesforce) with React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, salesforce

Currently setting up a mobile app using React Native (Expo), and I would like to validate the user using only the pin (not password), using PIN Protect. Is there documentation available to authenticate the user using their PIN with Rest API.

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/04/adding-salesforce-pin-security-to-native-and-hybrid-mobile-apps

Comment: You mean  LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync(options): https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/local-authentication/#localauthenticationgetenrolledlevelasync

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately, I am looking to validate the pin that is assigned to the Salesforce account, instead of the local pin of the device. I should have clarified this.